# How to design relation between Controller, Component, View and Helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a trouble with software design. I want to design a relation between Controller, Component, View and Helper. Ihave these models `Aricle`, `Product`, `List` . And in contents of `Article` and `Product` there are lists tags in form of `[LIST=1]`.

So I'd like to render these lists and inject them into content in place of tags. I thought that good idea would be a `ListRendererHelper` which would render lists inside of `View` like this `$this->ListRenderer->renderList($listId)`. And it would be a good idea if I list ids in database, but I should obtain it from content. And this is not good practice to manipulate with objects inside of `View` nor insert a lot of PHP code in `View`.

So I think that best place to manipulate content is `Controller`, and here obtain the lists ids. But I shouldn't use `Helper` in `Controller` so I think that I should make a `Component` for `Controller`. And here is my problem, because I will have to write render code twice in `Component` and in `Helper` which is against DRY. Other solution is to call `Helper` inside `Component` but that would be a MVC break too. So anyone have an idea how to design it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating data in a controller and render code in a component? Calling a helper inside a component? What the...? From where did you get these plain wrong ideas? You've understood MVC completely wrong.

You want a model method to get your data or to manipulate data. All data fetching and maniplation should happen in the model layer.

```
MyModel::getSomeFancyData($arg1, $arg2);
MyModel::manipulateMyFancyData($data);
```

The controller just passes the data along to the view. Controllers should be always as slim as possible.

```
$this->set('fancyData', $this->Model->getSomeFancyData());
```

Inside the view use a helper for recurring view logic. If you need to render large chunks for HTML that repeat better use an element or call that element from inside a helper.

I suggest you to read about the basics of MVC and CakePHP:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html

This isn't specific to CakePHP, you won't have a benefit from any framework if you're not able to apply the basic concepts like MVC to them.

Comment: I know those principles, but I'm confused. Can I use not related model inside another model?

Comment: And what is the best way to render an element() inside a helper?

Comment: ClassRegistry::init() to load another model. By using the view class: $this->_View->element() in the helper; If you know the principles why are you asking for MVC violations like using helpers in components?

Comment: I know MVC too little then. And wasn't sure. So I made it like this: First I get the collection of Lists in slider with `preg_match_all` and `find('all')`. Attach it to `$article` data. In controller I just pass it to the view. And later in view I use `Helper` to process `'content'`. Helper detects lists once more with `preg_match_all` and then renders each list with `element()`. After that injects lists into `'content'`. Sounds good?

Comment: No idea what you're doing without seeing the code. That you need preg_match_all() for that sounds scary and wrong. I would seriously recommend you to do the blog tutorial (again) or do the basic training course offered here http://training.cakephp.org/.

Comment: Why usage of preg_match_all() is bad and scary idea?